# Entity Framework Core - Customise Scaffolding

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In Entity Framework 6 we can add the T4 templates the scaffolding uses by running

```
Install-Package EntityFramework.CodeTemplates.CSharp
```

But in Entity Framework Core the scaffolding system does not appear to use T4 templates, nor does it seem like the scaffolding can be customised. It seems to be all in c# classes eg.

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/a508f37cf5a0246e9b92d05429153c3d817ad5ec/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Core/Scaffolding/Internal/EntityTypeWriter.cs

Is there any way to customise the output from the scaffold?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a special, yet-to-be-documented hook to override design-time services:

```
class Startup
{
    public static void ConfigureDesignTimeServices(IServiceCollection services)
        => services.AddSingleton<EntityTypeWriter, MyEntityTypeWriter>();
}
```

Then implement your custom generator.

```
class MyEntityTypeWriter : EntityTypeWriter
{
    public EntityTypeWriter(CSharpUtilities cSharpUtilities)
        : base(cSharpUtilities)
    {
    }

    // TODO: Override with custom implementation
}
```

**Update:** See [Yehuda Goldenberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7203328/yehuda-goldenberg)'s answer for another way to do this in EF Core 1.0.2+.

Comment: OK great I can see over in ScaffoldingServiceCollectionExtensions.cs how that works.

Comment: One of our goals in EF Core was to keep the framework open and extensible. You're effectively using a "back door" here. We promise to make this easier with support for templates (issue [#4038](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4038)).

Comment: I this now available and are there any tutorials i would like all of my poco database classes to extend my base class. Actually i think i will create a new question for that

Answer (score 6):

In .Net Core 1.1, the way to override design-time services is to implement the IDesignTimeServices interface in the startup assembly. For example:

```
public class MyDesignTimeServices : IDesignTimeServices
{
    public void ConfigureDesignTimeServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<EntityTypeWriter, MyEntityTypeWriter>();
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<DbContextWriter, MybContextWriter>();

    }
}
```

See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5617

Comment: This approach will also be enabled in EF Core 1.0.2

Comment: In EF Core 2.0.0 the classes are called `CSharpDbContextGenerator` and `CSharpEntityTypeGenerator`