# .NET Core Entity Framework database first generate model to inherit from base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

I managed to accomplish this and have updated the below to show how I did it. If there is a more elegant solution, I am interested :)

Preface: I am trying to move from Entity Framework 6 to Entity Framework Core. I have an existing database. I am doing Database First generation. I generate the classes using the "scaffold-dbContext" command in the console to do this. Ok that is fine. However I want all the generated classes to inherit from a simple base class. This is the gist of the entire base class:

```
public class MyEntityBase
{
    public MyEntityBase()
    {
    }
}
```

So if there is a table in the database called customer, I would like the resulting generated class to start off with:

```
public partial class Customer : MyEntityBase
```

I could do this in EF6 by changing the T4 file in the appropriate spot. I managed to do it in EF Core via the following.

A bit more info first. In my solution to start I have two projects. One is the "Web" project, created as an ASP.NET Core Web application. The other is the "Core" project, created as a .NET Core class library. This is where the Context file and Entity classes will live. It is also where MyEntityBase lives.

Ok,  I added a class file called MyDesignTimeServices.cs to the Web project. The contents of that file are this:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Configuration.Internal;

namespace MySolution.Web
{
public class MyDesignTimeServices : IDesignTimeServices
{
    public void ConfigureDesignTimeServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        //serviceCollection.AddSingleton<EntityTypeWriter, MyEntityTypeWriter>();
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<DbContextWriter, MyDbContextWriter>();
    }
}

public class MyDbContextWriter : DbContextWriter
{
    public MyDbContextWriter(ScaffoldingUtilities scaffoldingUtilities, CSharpUtilities cSharpUtilities) : base(scaffoldingUtilities, cSharpUtilities) { }

    public override string WriteCode(ModelConfiguration modelConfiguration)
    {
        var code = base.WriteCode(modelConfiguration);
        code = code.Replace("});", "\tentity.HasBaseType<" + typeof(MySolution.Core.MyEntityBase).Name + ">();" + Environment.NewLine + "\t\t\t});");
        return code;
    }
}

public class MyEntityTypeWriter : EntityTypeWriter
{
    public MyEntityTypeWriter(CSharpUtilities cSharpUtilities) : base(cSharpUtilities) { }

    public override string WriteCode(EntityConfiguration entityConfiguration)
    {
        // Get the default code of the entity class.
        var code = base.WriteCode(entityConfiguration);

        // We need to find the spot after the name of the class so we can add its inheritance.
        var classDeclaration = "public partial class ";
        var classDeclarationIndex = code.IndexOf(classDeclaration);
        if (classDeclarationIndex != -1)
        {
            // Remove anything in front of the class name, so that we can look for the first carriage return.
            var startsWithClassName = code.Substring(classDeclarationIndex + classDeclaration.Length);
            var afterClassNameIndex = startsWithClassName.IndexOf((char)13);
            if (afterClassNameIndex != -1)
            {
                // This is the spot where we want to insert our inheritance declaration.
                var insertIndex = classDeclarationIndex + classDeclaration.Length + afterClassNameIndex;

                // Insert our inheritance declaration.
                code = code.Substring(0, insertIndex) + " : " + typeof(MyEntityBase.Core.MyEntityBase).Name + code.Substring(insertIndex);
            }
        }

        return code;
    }
}
}
```

Build solution. Then when I run the Scaffold-DbContext command in the package manager console, I make sure the Default project dropdown choice is set to the Core project.

Comment: Have you take a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37679367/entity-framework-core-customise-scaffolding

Comment: Thank you, that helped to point me in the right direction. I was able to accomplish what I needed and I have updated my question to show how I did it.

Comment: This doesn't compile with core 2.0, am I missing some includes, or have they changed everything again?

Comment: I don't know about 2.0, all I can tell you is that I did the above in Core 1.1

Comment: In 2.0, the types have been changed 
DBContextWriter is now CSharpDbContextGenerator
EntityTypeWriter is now CSharpEntityTypeGenerator
Documentation also state that it may change, those are not stable APIs

Comment: For .net core 2.0 see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40728223/entity-framework-core-customize-scaffolding