# EF Core - Scaffolding to NodaTime types?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, ef-core-3.1, nodatime

I'm wondering, if there is any way in EntityFramework 6 and EFCore 3.1 of customize scaffolding, so e.g. SQLServer `date` will become `NodaTime.LocalDate` and SQLServer `datetime` (or `datetime2`) will be converted to `NodaTime.Instant`?

If so - could anyone give me an example how can it be done?

I found something like here: [Entity Framework Core - Customise Scaffolding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37679367/entity-framework-core-customise-scaffolding), but I cannot find any particular things for type-related code writing.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but do you think it could be something related to using `OnModelCreating` and implementing `property.SetValueConverter()` for your `DateTime` properties?

Comment: @NateW Generally - I don't know anything about possibilities of scaffolding customization, except sth like this I found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37679367/entity-framework-core-customise-scaffolding , https://blog.tonysneed.com/2018/05/27/customize-ef-core-scaffolding-with-handlebars-templates/

I would like to get possibility that anytime I need to scaffold model (i.e. model has changed) I will always obtain the same datatypes. If I understand you correctly (maybe not) - changes to OnModelCreating probably wouldn't be "constant".

Comment: My underlying shortfall in being able to understand your question is that I haven't ever encountered NodaTime before. But yes, I think you're right. My suggestion is on the side of interpreting the data out of the database into the pocos, and your question is on the side of scaffolding the creation of the pocos. So, this probably isn't the right solution path.

Comment: @NateW Generally - I tried to just replace DateTime with proper NodaTime equivalents (`LocalDate`, `Instant`, depending on SQLServer types) and it worked very fine (excepts problems with declaring NodaTime types for EF OData), but due to quite large number of item types I would like to have an automatic way to make sure it always be as I require.

Comment: Ah, I see. Something better than scaffolding the classes with `DateTime` and then using the Find and Replace tool...

Comment: @NateW in theory yes - but using replacement won't know if field in Db was originally `date` or `datetime`, and this should define whether to use `LocalDate` or `Instant`

Answer (score 0):

This was discussed in https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/20114

The recommendation is to use the [EFCore.SqlServer.NodaTime](https://github.com/StevenRasmussen/EFCore.SqlServer.NodaTime) library.

Comment: Thanks, just to make sure - this package works for code generation/scaffolding too?

Comment: And second thought - it seems that anyway I have second issue with Noda which may make it unusable for me: https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1626

Comment: Not sure about the scaffolding.  Try it and let us know please.  But yeah - that OData issue seems problematic.